# How can you orthogonalize a set of vectors

Tags: math, vector, orthogonal

I have been reading "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics" and there is a chapter exercise (Chapter 2. Question 2) that despite rereading the chapter and researching, I can not seem to understand. How can I "Orthogonalize the following set of vectors"

e1 = ( sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2, 0 )

e2 = ( -1, 1, -1 )

e3 = ( 0, -2, -2 )

Also, what does it mean to "Orthogonalize a set of vectors"?

Comment: You should ask on [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Gram-Schmidt Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) is the typical method used to derive an [orthonormal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) for the [spanned space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) defined by a collection of [linearly independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) vectors.  In the case you describe, since e1, e2 and e3 are linearly independent, Gram-Schmidt can be used to generate three mutually orthogonal vectors of unit length e1', e2' and e3' which is an orthonormal basis of the linear span of your original vectors.

Comment: Does it matter in this case? Doesn't [1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1], suffice?

Comment: @Jacob: generally orthogonalizing a set of vectors preserves not only the space that is spanned, but also the subspace spanned by each prefix of the sequence of vectors.  Your example doesn't suffice because [1 0 0] does not span the same subspace as the questioner's e1.